# By selecting a class, another div display none in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() { 

         jQuery( "li.post_link_history.current" ).click(function() {
    jQuery( "div#rating-anchor" ).css( "display", "none !important" );
    }); 
});
```

//or

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
       if(jQuery('li.post_link_history.current').attr('class')=='current')
        {
             jQuery('div#rating-anchor').not(jQuery(this)).css('display','none !important');
        }
    });
```

How can I "By selecting a class, another div display none in jquery"?

Comment: `.css( "display", "none !important" )` ... -> `.hide()`

Answer (score 0):

Your display style value is not valid for inline styles

```
jQuery( "div#rating-anchor" ).css( "display", "none" );//or just call the hide() method
```

Comment: I am trying this for interactionlibrary.jacklynn.com/wiki/direction/?action=history but not working? –

Answer (score 0):

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function() { 

        jQuery( "li.post_link_history" ).click(function() {
              jQuery( "div#rating-anchor" ).hide();
        });
       //or 
       jQuery( "li.current" ).click(function() {
        jQuery( "div#rating-anchor" ).hide();
        }); 
       //or use an common class for "li" ex:"commonli"
 jQuery( ".commonli" ).click(function() {
         if(jQuery(this).hasClass("current")){
           jQuery( "div#rating-anchor" ).hide();
         }
        });

    });
```

.hide() method will hide the division.
edited... current and post_link_history are different classes..so use any one

Comment: I am trying this for http://interactionlibrary.jacklynn.com/wiki/direction/?action=history but not working?

Comment: jsfiddle demo..or html

Comment: check i edited it... current and post_link_history are different classes..so use any one..

Comment: Is not possible this?

Comment: use a common class for li and bind click event to it..inside callback function check for  current class..see i edited it....